# Error al usar una base de datos en mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, datatables

Soy nuevo e intento usar bases de datos, en mi codigo solo tengo esto:

```
    create database prueba; 
    use prueba;
    create table Usuario(id int, email varchar(255), username varchar(50));
    alter table Usuario add edad int;
```

De salida tengo un error "Error.Code:1007.Can't create database 'pruebas', database  exists"
Quisiera saber porque no puedo usar la base de datos que ya cree en la primera linea

Answer (score 0):

El error puede ser que ya en una previa ejecución se había creado la db, intenta comentar o quitar la primera línea de tu script. O verifica en tu manejador de db si ya existe tu db para que no tengas que intentar crearla si ya existe.